# cat > somefile << "EOF" or EOF, that make differnet result on bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I write the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEST_VAR="HELLO"

cat > test-1.txt << EOF
TEST_VAR is ${TEST_VAR}
EOF

cat > test-2.txt << "EOF"
TEST_VAR is ${TEST_VAR}
EOF
```

But I found the results are different:

`test-1.txt` is `TEST_VAR is HELLO`

And:

`test-2.txt` is `TEST_VAR is ${TEST_VAR}`

Could anyone help to explain it?

Comment: You mention Bash, but the shebang says `sh`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **"** in the following line is causing the issue:

```
cat > test-2.txt << "EOF"
```

The reason is in **man bash**: when quoted there is no parameter expansion.

```
Here Documents
   This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the  lines  read
   up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.

   The format of here-documents is:

          <<[-]word
                  here-document
          delimiter

   No  parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is
   the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter  expansion,
   command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \<newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

   If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts
   to be indented in a natural fashion.
```

Answer (score 0):

`"EOF"` will automatically escape all special characters, and print them as is, where `EOF` does not, and therefore puts the value.

Instead of `"EOF"` you could also use `\EOF`.